# 401 Invalid JWT Token Lexik

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, jwt

I'm not sure why i Keep getting a wrong bearer token.

```
{
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}
```

When i debug it on https://jwt.io/ i also get a Invalid Signature Response
even tho the data is correct.

What causes this ? Are my configs wrong ?

Any help is welcome

Here is my `security.yaml`.

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true

password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\BackendUser:
        algorithm: auto
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\BackendUser
            property: email
    auth_token:
        id: App\Security\AuthTokenUserProvider
    jwt:
        id: App\Security\JwtUserProvider

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        provider: auth_token
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator

    api:
       pattern:   ^/api
       stateless: true
       provider: jwt
       guard:
           authenticators:
               - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    easy_admin:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\EasyAdminAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # Easy Admin Routes
    - { path: ^/admin/login,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin,            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # Api Routes
    - { path: ^/api/login,        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # Translations
    - { path: ^/translations,                   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/translations/grid,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here is my `lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml`

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
token_ttl: 2592000 # token TTL in seconds, defaults to 1 hour
user_identity_field: token
```

Not sure what other infos you might need.
Let me know and i will update the post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i share with you my config of my file security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: argon2i

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-   user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        registration:
            pattern: ^/api/users
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            methods: [POST]
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

You can share screen or explain how you send your request to the app ? (because you must send it from postman for example)